# How to set NetBeans project properties to use Java 7?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, java-7, try-with-resources

I am new to NetBeans, and have previously been using Eclipse. I have started using NetBeans now because I need to learn a variety of Java EE concept, and I have found more relevant tutorials for the NetBeans IDE. A lot of the abstract concepts in EE still has me confused, so I have found that step-by-step holding hands-tutorials works best for me for now.

I have however met a dead end. I am following [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html), on setting up a web service client. However, one of the lines include a try-with-resource statement, which is new in java 7. Picture here:

[image]

When I started this tutorial, I was using Netbeans 7.1.3, with Glassfish 3.1.2. I knew it didn't have support for EE7, so i downloaded NetBeans 8.0.1 with Glassfish 4.1. I have realized later on that the try-with-resources is a part of SE, and my upgrade was in this matter reduntant.

I figured there was something wrong with my project settings, so i right-clicked it and opened it's properties. Under the Libraries option, I found that the JDK was correctly set to Java 1.7 (update 51). Picture here:

[image]

I also checked the oter options, and under Run I found that Java EE is set to 6, even though Glassfish 4.1 is selected as server. I figured this was an implementation of EE7, but the option is locked to EE6. This confuses me a bit, but shouldn't be the cause of the problem. I still attach a picture of it, just in case it is relevant:

[image]

So what is wrong with my Java settings for this project? Why can't it accept a Java 7 feature, when it seems like it is set to use Java 7? Are there other places where i need to set java version/home?

Comment: Have you looked at Sources -> Source/Binary format ?

Comment: I have now. And it works. I had simply overlooked that option. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use Java7 for the system library but compile your source code to be compatible with Java6.

To change this you have to go to sources in your project settings and change the source compatibility to Java7.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I had just overlooked that option. Thank you!